# SQLite Incomplete Time String

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, time, strftime

I have a table with incomplete time strings, such as '0:09.735' (minutes:seconds.milliseconds).

As the function strftime expects certain formats, such as '%H:%M:%f', I have "to complete" the incomplete timestring first.

```
SELECT
  strftime('%M:%f', '00:00:09.735', '+2.5 seconds') AS Duration1, -- works correctly
  strftime('%M:%f', '0:00:09.735',  '+2.5 seconds') AS Duration2, -- shows NULL
  strftime('%M:%f', '0:09.735',     '+2.5 seconds') AS Duration3, -- shows NULL
  strftime('%M:%f', '9.735',        '+2.5 seconds') AS Duration4  -- shows incorrect result
```

The first strftime function with the complete timestring shows the correct result, the second, third, and fourth one with the incomplete timestring do not.

Is there a flexible way that can convert all forms of incomplete timestrings into complete ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the dot and the milliseconds are always there, you can use string functions to manipulate the times:

```
SELECT strftime(
         '%M:%f',
         SUBSTR('00:00:00', 1, 9 - INSTR(timestring, '.')) || timestring, 
         '+2.5 seconds'
       ) result
FROM tablename
```

Replace `timestring` with the name of the column.

But it would be better to update the column:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET timestring = SUBSTR('00:00:00', 1, 9 - INSTR(timestring, '.')) || timestring
```

so you have valid time values for SQLite.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cba4bf2497509dbddfa12adf40442959).